# Can I specify two different styles within one CSS class?

Tags: html, css

The HTML:

```
<span class="foo">Hello</span>
```

I want the CSS class "foo" to be defined as follows: the first letter of the enclosed content is red, and the rest of the characters are green. Is this possible?

EDIT:

What if I want something like the opposite? I want the first letter to be EXCLUDED from any styling (except any parent styling), and all the rest of the letters to be green.

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS3/Selectors/pseudo-elements/:first-letter

Comment: What about the opposite? (see question edit)

Comment: @Tim You need to reset the styles in `:first-letter` selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`first-letter` pseudo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3A%3Afirst-letter):

```
.foo { color: green; display: inline-block; }

.foo:first-letter { color: red; }
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLapy/

---

**Note:** the `:first-letter` selector will not work on an `inline` element.
You have to use either `block`, `inline-block` or `table`.

Comment: I edited it once and got accepted, but you changed it back. "the first letter of the enclosed content is red" Please re-read the question. Your colors are backwards.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall - Sorry - I didn't realize. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Tim - You can't. You have to manually override any styles you applied to the element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [:first-letter](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp) pseudo selector.

```
span.foo:first-letter
{
font-size:200%;
color:#8A2BE2;
}
```

Comment: @Tim kinda copied Joseph Siller…

Comment: Timestamp indicates Andrzej was first.

Comment: @user1090389 - Joseph posted his answer circa 30 seconds before as far I remember.- but to be honest, is your own answer different?

Comment: I will +1 you to even the score. Its true that if someone already posted the same answer you shouldn't duplicate it, but you were only 30 seconds behind so I think its safe to assume you just overlapped. You may want to delete your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the first-letter pseudo element to do this.

Example:

```
.foo{ color: red; }
```

and

```
.foo:first-letter{ color:green; }
```

The first-letter pseudo element (hence the name) will change the property of the first letter in the span.

You can read more on how to do this @ http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp

EDIT:

If you want to do the opposite, and have the first letter be excluded from the style, the easiest way would be to exclude the first letter from the span entirely. You could also change the color of the first letter to the color of the rest of the text on the page (default color) .

Comment: Well, the easiest way would be to exclude the first letter from the span.   Another way would be to make the first letter of the span, the same color as the rest of the text on the page.